# Fancybox not showing over flowplayer IE issue?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, fancybox, flowplayer

I'm having a really strange issue, I have a flowplayer video, and next to that is an image that when clicked shows in a fancybox, in webkit, mozilla it works fine, but IE decides to put the video in front of the slide.

I thought this might be related to the z-index, but everything seems fine there. Fancybox gives the loading image a z-index of 1200 which is way above what it needs to be.

Here is a link to the page

http://bit.ly/bEechI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the same problem, if i figure it out, i'll let u kno

answer: changing the wmode to transparent should fix it.

flowplayer("myDiv", {src: '/flowplayer.swf', wmode: 'transparent'}, {
  // flowplayer config
});